# Meteor method not saving to database after translating autodesk view and data api

Tags: meteor, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have been creating an autodesk 3D viewer system for a project.

I am trying to upload a 3D model file(*.rvt extension) to my meteor server and then translate it using the Autodesk View and Data API.

I am using [meteor-uploads](https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads) to upload the files to the system. Once this upload is done, the callback function triggers a Meteor Method call to upload this file to the Autodesk API and traslate it.

The client code for the meteor upload:

```
Template.uploader.helpers({
    afterUpload: function(){
        return {
            finished:function(index,fileinfo,content){
                console.log(fileinfo);
                Meteor.call('translateFile', fileinfo.name, function(err,result){
                    console.log(result);
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The console log prints undefined even before the upload is started.
Following is the server code

```
translateFile:function(name){
    var filename =process.env.PWD + '/.data/' + name ;
    var bucket =
        'model'
        + new Date ().toISOString ().replace (/T/, '-').replace (/:+/g, '-').replace (/\..+/, '')
        + '-' + lmv.Lmv.getToken ().toLowerCase ().replace (/\W+/g, '') ;
    var policy ='persistent' ;
    console.log(bucket);

    async.waterfall ([
        function (callbacks1) {
            console.log ('createBucketIfNotExist') ;
            new lmv.Lmv(bucket).createBucketIfNotExist (policy)
                .on ('success', function (data) {
                    console.log ('Bucket already or now exist!') ;
                    callbacks1 (null, data) ;
                })
                .on ('fail', function (err) {
                    console.log ('Failed to create bucket!') ;
                    callbacks1 (err) ;
                })
            ;
        },

        function (arg1, callbacks2) {
            console.log ('async upload') ;
            new lmv.Lmv(bucket).uploadFile (filename)
                .on ('success', function (data) {
                    console.log (filename + ' uploaded.') ;
                    callbacks2 (null, data) ;
                })
                .on ('fail', function (err) {
                    console.log ('Failed to upload ' + filename + '!') ;
                    callbacks2 (err) ;
                })
            ;
        },

        function (arg1, callbacks3) {
            console.log ('Launching translation') ;
            var urn =JSON.parse (arg1).objects [0].id ;
            new lmv.Lmv (bucket).register (urn)
                .on ('success', function (data) {
                    console.log ('Translation requested.') ;
                    callbacks3 (null, data) ;
                })
                .on ('fail', function (err) {
                    console.log ('Failed to request translation!') ;
                    callbacks3 (err) ;
                })
            ;
        }

    ], function (err, results) {
        console.log(results.urn);
        console.log(results);
        console.log(err);
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            return err;
        }
        if(results){
            Document.insert({urn:results.urn,name:name});
            console.log('inserting');
        }
    }) ;

    console.log('---------------------HERE AT THE END---------------------')

},
```

and the client code is:

```
Meteor.call('translateFile', name, function(err,result){
    console.log(result);
})
```

The thing is the method returns right away with a value of undefined and all the console logs inside the async.waterfall get printed in the right order except the one in the last callback "inserting". This is because the Document.insert function doesn't get called/fired and I dont even get an error.

I have tried the Futures library to no use. I even tried putting the insert function inside a different method, still no use.

Any ideas would be really helpful. I am happy to provide more information if necessary.

Comment: Refer this documentation. https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/viewer-javascript-tutorial/blob/master/chapters/chapter-2b.md

Comment: I am using that as the base to create this upload in the meteor system. It is more to do with the way meteor method works than the way autodesk does the upload.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess what's going wrong and I'm not familiar with Meteor, which I guess doesn't really matter in that case. Did you try the npm package at https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/view-and-data-npm?

Install version 1.0.7 because the latest version is not up-to-date with the current API which has been modified recently.

It's pretty straightforward to upload and translate files with that, an example is available in the readme and the test